# In Javascript, how to import only the function and not the class or object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code below:

```
import { Router } from 'express'
.
.
.
const router = Router()
```

How the below code can be used

```
router.post('/authenticate', AuthController.authenticate)
```

as:

`post('/authenticate', AuthController.authenticate)`

How do I import only the function and not the class, type or the object?

Comment: only exports express Router, not mehod https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js. You can do const post = Router().post

Answer (score 1):

```
const post = Router().post
```

You should be able to use `post('/authenticate', AuthController.authenticate)` after that.

Comment: You may have to do `const r = Router(), post = r.post.bind(r)`; I don't know if this is necessary in this particular case, but depending on how the object is implemented this may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the whole package.

```
import { Router } from 'express'
.
.
.
const post = Router().post
```

The above snippet will still import the whole file but it will only assign a specific function to a variable.